# jQuery draggable - reactivating after returning cancel from drag event

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

My issue is that I have a set of divs. When I am dragging any of them and they reach the side (not exactly the side, but the equivalent of the side. So it does not always snap to the side of another div, but when it reaches the coordinates of that side, see image below)

[image]

of another within a certain variance it is supposed to snap to the side of the other div. For example

I am dragging horizontally and the div is to snap to x=100 as soon as it reaches x=120. So the variance is 20 in this case and it executes the snap at x=100.

What I am doing is utilizing the drag and once I reach 100 I force the div to x=120 and return false in the drag event.

My issue is that since I am still holding down the mouse left button I am unable to drag any further at that point and also unable to reenable the drag.

Is there a way that I can undo the cancel and reactivate the drag motion when the mouse moves after the snap.

What I have tried and did not work (assuming it is because the mouse button is still held down):

1. I  Tried a `setTimeout` to trigger a mouse up and click.  Did not work.
2. I tried the `JS` `createEvent`, which is practically the same I believe and did not work.
3. I tried to trigger the drag event. Did not work.

Google did not seem to return anything of any help.  I feel like I am beating my head against a wall right now.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

If any additional information is required, please let me know.

Thank you,
Jeff

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Since the element is not in the same plane as the draggable, you can add another element that is as tall as the parent. This way you can use Snap to that element in your Drag.

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
  function makeHidden(s) {
    var $targets = $(s);
    $targets.each(function(i, el) {
      var $el = $(el);
      $("<div>", {
        class: "hidden"
      }).css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: $el.css("left"),
        width: $el.width() + "px",
        height: $el.parent().height() + "px"
      }).insertAfter(el);
    });
  }

  $("#drag-1").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: "parent",
    snap: ".hidden",
    snapMode: "outer",
    snapTolerance: 20
  });

  makeHidden(".fixed");
});
```

```css
.draggable,
.fixed {
  width: 90px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
}

.ui-widget-header p,
.ui-widget-content p {
  margin: 0;
}

#play-pen {
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
}

#fixed-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 120px;
}

#drag-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="play-pen" class="ui-widget-header">
  <div id="drag-1" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="fixed-1" class="fixed ui-widget-content">
    <p>Fixed 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For `makeHidden()` you can pass in a Selector, Element, or jQuery Object. If you pass in a Selector or jQuery Object, it will work for one or all of the elements that match. If you have 2 or 3 fixed elements, it will make hidden items for each.

See more:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snap
- https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapMode
- https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapTolerance

If the number of fixed elements change, you may want to move `makeHidden()` into the Start callback for Draggable. Then destroy them in Stop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It is most definitely a good starting point rather than having to rewrite a lot of code.  I shall see if I can also make this work to snap to the middle vertically and horizontally.  I shall have to look deeper into the snap options of draggable.

Comment: @Jeff I hope this helps and you feel like upvoting or marking it as the answer. Also you can change `snapMode` to `"both"` and see it snap to both outside and inside edges.

Comment: Twisty Thanks again.  I am still trying to find the best solution for the snapping to the middle of elements. Tried the same method with used for the outer and inner.  Am in the process of extending to get more data on position and such and adding a snapped event.  However, no true solution at this time.  I voted your solution up as it is a great start.  Thanks again.